# XSL - How to create a table from XML with multiple elements of the same name

Tags: html, xml, xslt, html-table

I want to create a table which would look  like this:

[image: Table]

from this typical XML file

```
<test>
<criteria nom="DR">
    <abbr>DR</abbr>
    <value>0.123456</value>
    <value>0.134679</value>
    <value>0.976431</value>
    <rating></rating>
</criteria>
<criteria nom="MOTA">
    <abbr>MOTA</abbr>
    <value>0.132465</value>
    <value>0.321645</value>
    <value>0.649715</value>
    <rating></rating>
</criteria>
<criteria nom="PFR">
    <abbr>PFR</abbr>
    <value>0.914375</value>
    <value>0.467985</value>
    <value>0.162356</value>
    <rating></rating>
</criteria>
</test>
```

but I can't figure how to do it.
Googled it AND searched here on stackoverflow but no success.

My code for creating the table is currently presented like this:

```
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"/>
<xsl:template match="/">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
            <title>YAML</title>
        </head>

        <body>
            <table width="1000" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="test/criteria">
                    <th scope="col"><xsl:value-of select="@nom" /></th>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>

            <xsl:for-each select="test/criteria/value">
                <tr>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </table>

        </body>
    </html>

</xsl:template>
```

but the current output for this code is the following:
[image: current table]
How can I do this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: by the way, I acknowlege that this title is extremely unclear. If you have any idea on how to clarify it, i'll be happy to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your current `xsl:for-each` on `test/criteria/value` to this..

```
<xsl:for-each select="test/criteria[1]/value">
    <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
    <tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="/test/criteria/value[$pos]">
            <td><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></td>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

That is to say, select only the `value` elements in the first criteria, get the position, and then get all criteria `value` elements that occur in that position as they are the ones that form your row.

Note that this does assume all `criteria` have the same number of `value` nodes.

Full XSLT....

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
            <title>YAML</title>
        </head>

        <body>
            <table width="1000" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="test/criteria">
                    <th scope="col"><xsl:value-of select="@nom" /></th>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>

            <xsl:for-each select="test/criteria[1]/value">
                <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
                <tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="/test/criteria/value[$pos]">
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></td>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="test/criteria">
    <tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="value">
            <td><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></td>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

In place of:

```
<xsl:for-each select="test/criteria/value">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: does not work. i now have 3 rows, but with the data not where it should be